# SHA Key with Windows and MsysGit/Free CopSSH

Tags: windows, putty, copssh

OS (for <strike>better or</strike> worse) is XP

I am having some issues, I have seen other questions but none seem to apply to me.

1. I have CopSSH installed and I can log in using cleartext password.
2. Now I want to upgrade that to SHA keys.
3. I use PuttyGen to get a public and private key
4. I then copy those into ~/.ssh and %ICW%/home/%un%/.ssh as id_rsa and id_rsa.pub.
5. I add the public key as follows....

Example Pubkey

```
---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
Comment: "rsa-key-20121115"
AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAIBdfRGHY4IYsUuDYzbgEy1wKXrszq5RVR4m2/gP
WJwLwiaNHpahfPeHmsG7nD7qeVNVp+sSVouApm70ZdfGnxzOHiBydtdOuco+sbqZ
irlyG9wS5yv8x9LFsGqZ34tbr8dgPXMdYnrJHJqUa3+ZMUNPXznRUzj/VTiwoS6/
jMHzkw==
---- END SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
```

Example known_host

```
<ServerName>,<IP>,localhost ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAIBdfRGHY4IYsUuDYzbgEy1wKXrszq5RVR4m2/gPWJwLwiaNHpahfPeHmsG7nD7qeVNVp+sSVouApm70ZdfGnxzOHiBydtdOuco+sbqZirlyG9wS5yv8x9LFsGqZ34tbr8dgPXMdYnrJHJqUa3+ZMUNPXznRUzj/VTiwoS6/jMHzkw== UN@SERVER
```

So now I add the generated private key to putty and try to connect but I see the following...

```
Server refused our key
```

It still allows me to log in using my password.

How can I get the Private Key auth to work?

Answer (score 0):

Check if Itefix FAQ https://www.itefix.no/i2/content/i-want-use-my-own-pka-key-pair-instead-one-generated-copssh can be helpful.